# Anchor and the fadeIn effect

Tags: jquery

I have some `<a>` tags on my page with the `myLink` class. When, the DOM is loaded, I want to `hide` and use `fadeIn` effect. But, using the code below I don't see any animation, what's wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.myLink').css('display','block')
                 .html('&nbsp;')
                 .hide()
                 .fadeIn('slow',function() { $(this).html('lorem'); });

});
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jEJz7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/E9uht/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/E9uht/

Hope it fits the cause `:)` Please lemme know if I missed anything!

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.myLink').css('display', 'block')
                 .html('&nbsp;') //<=if you comment me then I will show full link.:)
                 .hide('slow',function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        $(this).html('lorem');
                    });
    })


});​
```